# synchronization over network based on file size

Tags: windows, synchronization

Is there any (Windows based) software or tool is available which will **sync bidirectional** as well **based on file size**.

To clarify:

- If one file with a size of over 10GB is being synchronized over lan, **and**
- at the same time, a new file with a size of less than 1 gb is placed in a sync-enabled folder, **then**
- at that time, the synchronization of the larger file should pause, and the smaller file be synchronized first, in order to avoid bottlenecks in the network

I've tried out sugersync, syncables 360, good sync, visa versa , allway sync but none of them has the functionality I want.

Help would be really appreciated,

Thanks in advance to all.

Answer (score 2):

[Unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html) has most of what you are asking for, the only problem is the stopping in the middle, you can have unison run through small files first, then the largest last (`sortbysize`), and you can define bandwidth usage, but stopping it if a new file was created would require constant file system monitoring, and could cause real problems if accidentally placed on a directory where files are created and deleted with regularity (mail queues, print spools, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Frankly, I don't think you'll find any product that does what you request, mostly because the best way to handle bandwidth management is at the network layer.

In your case, I would setup a QOS rule at the perimeter and define bandwidth reservation for the specific path you want to prioritize.